# Pause and Resume a for Loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I need some way to pause and resume `for` loop. I have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paramsArray.count; i++) {
            var stringResponse: String!
            var urlString: String
            if paramsArray[i].arduinoHTTPPort == 80 {
                urlString = String(format: "http://%@/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [paramsArray[i].arduinoAddress, paramsArray[i].pinType.lowercaseString, paramsArray[i].arduinoPin])
            } else {
                urlString = String(format: "http://%@:%i/arduino/%@/%i/", arguments: [paramsArray[i].arduinoAddress, paramsArray[i].arduinoHTTPPort, paramsArray[i].pinType.lowercaseString, paramsArray[i].arduinoPin])
            }
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
                println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
                //Need to resume loop here
            }
            //Need to stop loop here
        }
```

How to stop and resume loop in swift, or is there any other ways to do such stops?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why does this loop need to be paused?

Comment: The whole method updates `UITableView`. Every cell should be updated step by stem, when device has a response from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of it as pausing a loop, think of the loop as building the number of things you need to manage and then managing when those things are done after the loop is complete.

Rather than directly execute your URL connections in the loop you should create `NSOperation` instances in the loop and add them to an `NSOperationQueue`. You can `suspend` and `resume` the queue, and you can also set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` so you can limit how many connections you're loading at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'loop' by repeatedly calling a function that performs the body of the 'loop'.  If you don't call the function, then you effectively 'pause'; when you do call the function, then the 'loop' iterates again.  Like such:

```
let body = { (i:Int) -> Void in
  if i < paramsArray.count {
    // Lots of stuff, and then
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest () {
      // Lots more stuff, and then
      body (i + 1)
    }
  }
}

body (0)
```