# Pause a for Loop for actions - Swift: Sprite Kit

Tags: for-loop, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to make a deer to jump ramdonly through different defined positions.

```
func deerJumping () {
   // The different locations are arranged ramdonly
   var places: [CGFloat] = [1124, 852, 1540, 1908, 628, 1736, 392].shuffled()
   //Then the for loop with the actions (jumps) between this positions
   for posc in places {
        //SKAction for the up and down
        //SKAction for the displacement left or right
        //Code for the deer to face the direction of the jump
        //Then run the action:
        deer.run(SKAction.group([jump, move]))
   }
}
```

The problem is that the loop is not waiting for the actions to finish before to go to the next position in the array.

There's this [Pause and Resume a for Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288913/pause-and-resume-a-for-loop) question that I find. It is about to create `NSOperation` instances in the loop and add them to an `NSOperationQueue` but sadly I am a beginner and I don't understand the solution so I have no idea how to apply it to my code.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why nothing is waiting is because you run all of your actions at the same time.  You want to create an array of actions and run it in sequence

```
func deerJumping () {
   // The different locations are arranged ramdonly
   var places: [CGFloat] = [1124, 852, 1540, 1908, 628, 1736, 392].shuffled()
   //Then the for loop with the actions (jumps) between this positions
   var actions = [SKAction]()
   for posc in places {
        //SKAction for the up and down
        //SKAction for the displacement left or right
        //Code for the deer to face the direction of the jump
        //Then run the action:
        actions.append(SKAction.sequence([jump, move]))
   }
   var deerRunning = SKAction.sequence(action)
   deer.run(deerRunning)

}
```

Now I have no idea why you want to pause and resume a for loop,  you are going to have to elaborate on that one before I can help you out.

Comment: Thanks so much KnightOfDragon. I think it could work! :)

Comment: I wanted to pause the loop to make the time to run the action before to itinerate to the next position.

Comment: I am not following you. Pausing the for loop does nothing

Comment: Ok, I try to explain myself: I want the deer to perform the actions (the jump) one after another with the for loop. As you said the for loop runs all the actions at the same time so I have thought that I needed to find a way to pause the loop the time to the deer to make the jump and then resume the loop to make the next jump and so on...

Comment: So you do not need to pause the for loop then

Comment: @Sersiego Forget the loop...thing. You may need a loop like in Knight0fDragon's example, to fill the array with actions. Generally, if you want to run actions at the same time, use group. But that is not what you need, and  what is proposed in this answer will work for you. Make a sequence and that's all (rather than a group).

Comment: oh I didn't even see in the code that he is grouping moving and jumping